# how to make laravel query with mid() in relation

Tags: php, laravel, model

8 project 
now everything working ok but i have question 
that in mysql i can run this

```
select * from table where mid(column_name,1,4) = 5
```

can i do something like this in laravel relation 
like i have `user` table and every user has  `voucher` 
i mean can i do something like this

```
User::getVoucherRelation()->where(mid(created_at,1,4),'=',$value)->get();
Model_name::Relation()->where(mid(column_name,1,6),'=',$value)->get();
```

ect 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with the function whereRaw(), i.e.:

```
User::getVoucherRelation()->whereRaw("mid(created_at,1,4) = $value")->get();
Model_name::Relation()->whereRaw("mid(column_name,1,6) = $value")->get();
```

You can review the functions here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: $a = User::getVoucherDetales()->whereRaw("mid(created_at,1,4) = 15")->get();
return $a;
i gat this Non-static method App\User::getVoucherDetales() should not be called statically and getVoucherDetales() is a relation one to many

Comment: This is another question, you asked how to make a query with mid() sql function and I have answered, IMHO, correctly. If you have other problems open another answer with the minimal code to reproduce the problem.